# Passing PHP variable into URL

Tags: php, google-maps

I have the code:

```
echo '<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=266%20Orms%20St%20Providence%20RI&key=mykey"  allowfullscreen> </iframe>' ;
```

I would like to pass the variable $street into the url, after **q=**, such as:

```
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=$street&key=mykey
```

The map is showing but the actual street from $street is not being recognized. Furthermore, how would I pass more than 1 variable? I tried passing $street and $city ,unsucessfully:

```
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=$street+city&key=mykey
```

Answer (score 2):

you're using single quotes, so you need to do concatenation:

```
echo '<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=' . urlencode($street) . '"  allowfullscreen> </iframe>';
```

Comment: @codEinsteinn SO is not the right site to learn php syntax, your question does not show any effort to research the problem

Comment: Actually I did research but the solutions did not work in my case, only yours.

Comment: @codEinsteinn one of the first pages of php manual (this first source you have to look in case of any php problems): http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try also this.

```
echo '<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q='.$street.'"  allowfullscreen> </iframe>';
```